# Any attribute or converter I can use to parse this JSON more efficiently?

Tags: json.net

I'm getting data back from a web service call. The response in XML looks like this:

```xml
<a:Response>     
     <a:Witness>
             <a:WitnessClass>
                <a:Witness>
                   <a:SomeProperty>SomeValue</a:CITY>
                   <a:Other>whatever</a:Other>
                </a:Witness>
             </a:WitnessClass>
      </a:Witness>
  </a:Response>
```

When I serialize the object using Newtonsoft, I get this (I'm storing the object as a Json string in the database):

```js
{
...other properties,
"Witness":
[
    {"Witness":
        {
            "SomeProperty":"SomeValue",
            "Other":"whatever"
        }
    }
]
}
```

The POCO I want to deserialize the json to looks like this:

```c#
 public class ResponseDto
{
   public virtual List<Witness> Witnesses { get; set; }
}
```

When I use this method, everything else deserializes without an issue, except the Witnesses list is null:

```c#
var dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponsetDto>(json);
```

I can get this to work if I do the following (but I was wondering if there's an attribute or something else I can do to make this work):

```c#
var dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseDto>(json);
dto.Witnesses = new List<Witness>();

var o = JObject.Parse(json);
var token = o["Witness"];
foreach (var child in token.Children())
{
    var innerWitness = child["Witness"];
    var witness = innerWitness.ToObject<Witness>();
    dto.Witnesses.Add(witness);
}

return dto;
```

**Edit**

I've been through the documentation on the Newtonsoft site, but I don't see anything that stands out. I've looked at (and tried) converters, but I don't see an example that allows me to do what I want.

**Further edit**

I've been able to get what I need by doing the following (based on an example on the Newtonsoft site), but I still want to know if there is a better/easier way to do this (I feel like I'm missing something):

```c#
[JsonExtensionData]
    private IDictionary<string, JToken> _additionalData;

[OnDeserialized]
private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
{
    //Witness is odd due to the structure of the response (Witness has an array of Witness)
    var o = _additionalData["Witness"];

    if (o != null)
    {
        Witnesses = new List<Witness>();
        foreach (var child in o.Children())
        {
            var innerWitness = child["Witness"];
            var witness = innerWitness.ToObject<Witness>();
            Witnesses.Add(witness);
        }
    }
}

public ResponseDto()
{
    _additionalData = new Dictionary<string, JToken>();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by *Any attribute or converter I can use to parse this JSON more efficiently?*  If you are having performance problems, see [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) by Eric Lippert, which states **Use a profiler or other analysis tool to determine empirically where the bottleneck is before you start investigating alternatives.**

That being said, your current use of a `private IDictionary<string, JToken> _additionalData;` to temporarily cache the witness list may not be ideal since you do not clear the dictionary after deserialization is complete, leading to persistent excess memory use and possible problems re-serializing your `ResponseDto` later on.

Instead, you can apply a [`ItemConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm) to your `Witnesses` property to handle the extra level of nesting:

```c#
public class ResponseDto
{
    [JsonProperty("Witness", ItemConverterType=typeof(WitnessConverter))]
    public virtual List<Witness> Witnesses { get; set; }
}

class WitnessConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(string.Format("To avoid infinite recursion, {0} must be applied statically through attributes, not added at run time in serialization settings.", this));
    }

    class WitnessDto
    {
        [JsonProperty(ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize)]
        public Witness Witness { get; set; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var dto = serializer.Deserialize<WitnessDto>(reader);
        return dto.Witness;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, new WitnessDto { Witness = (Witness)value });
    }
}

public class Witness
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
    public string Other { get; set; }
}
```

Here I used a `WitnessDto` rather than loading to a `JObject` due to a recommendation given in the article [11 Ways to Improve JSON Performance & Usage](https://stackify.com/top-11-json-performance-usage-tips/):

> If at all possible, make sure you have a class that matches the JSON
>   structure you are working with. Parsing generic JSON to a JSON.net
>   JObject or generic dictionaries with FastJson is slower (~20%) than
>   reading that data in to a defined class type. This is likely because a
>   lot more meta data is tracked with the generic Json.NET’s JObject,
>   JArray, JValue objects.

However, you should profile yourself to confirm.

Comment: Thanks! That works. I tried using a custom converter before I posted, but couldn't get it to work (not really familiar with anything outside of simple serialization/deserialization). The extra layer of nesting (with the same name) was giving me fits.